# Read Text File with Names Containing Brackets?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I find something interesting when I try to read text files from a folder:

```
 $files = Get-ChildrenItem "C:\MyFolder" -Recursive | ?{$_.Extension -like '.txt'}
 foreach ($file in $files) {
    [string]fileFullName = $file.FullName
    $content = Get-Content -Path $fileName
    ....
 }
```

I encountered some exceptions if file names contains [ and ] chars, for example, a[1].txt.

I guess that every thing is object in PS. Therefore, as for my understanding,  [..] in file names maybe treated as index access. Is there any way to deal with files with brackets?

Answer (score 1):

You want `-LiteralPath`:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\MyFolder" -Recurse | ? { $_.Extension -like '.txt' }

foreach ($file in $files) {
    [string]$fileFullName = $file.FullName
    $content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $fileFullName
    $content
}
```

From detailed help () you willsee:

> -LiteralPath 
>           Specifies the path to an item. Unlike Path, the value of LiteralPath is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are
>   interpreted as wildcards. If the path includes escape characters,
>   enclose it in single quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell
>   Windows  PowerShell not to interpret any characters as escape
>   sequences.